# 8.1 Universal App. Setting textbox focus on load

Tags: c#, xaml, focus, win-universal-app, windows-10

I was wondering if there was a way to force focus to a textbox in a Windows 8.1 Universal app?

I've been playing around with publishing to Window 10 IoT on the raspberry pi 2. While publishing to it I noticed that the only textbox does not pickup focus, despite it doing so while running locally.

I've tried a couple things like:

```
        private void txtFocus_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
             this.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);
        }

        public MainPage()
        {
             this.InitializeComponent();
             txtFocus.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);
        }
```

As well as setting it on the XAML:

```
        <TextBox x:Name="txtFocus" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,305,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="I Would Like Focus" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="540" Height="70" FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=txtFocus}" Loaded="txtFocus_Loaded"/>
```

But none of this seems to work, any ideas why this happens or a possible solution to this would be appreciated.

Edit: The following seemed to sort my problem

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
    }

    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtFocus.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);
    }
```

Comment: After looking through some articles I came across this http://wpf.2000things.com/tag/focus/ 
with #311 solving my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would give the illusion of focus, and get back to the original view once the user has entered text

Edit: what I meant is that once the textbook is selected the other buttons or whatever you have would be not visible and textbook size would increase, after the text entry, everything goes back to the original

Answer (score 0):

Came across this as I was porting my Windows8.1 apps to Windows10 universal app and had to give a textbox the focus if nothing entered.

Achieved by simply using

```
txtFocus.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);
```

But also had to [enable tablet mode](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-force-tablet-mode-windows-10) on my device so watch for that one as the keyboard was not visible even after giving the textbox the focus.